# Merge hashes of arrays based on similar positions with Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, merge

I have the following two hashes with arrays as values.

```
a = {
  "Us" => [["1", ["1", "2"]], ["2", ["1"]]],
  "Pa" => [["1", ["1", "3", "5"]], ["4", ["7"]]]
}
b = {
  "Us" => [["1", ["F", "O"]], ["2", ["N"]]],
  "Pa" => [["1", ["S", "D", "H"]], ["4", ["K"]]]
}
```

I'm trying to merge the hashes to get a final has like this:

```
c = {
  "Us" => [["1", ["1|F", "2|O"]], ["2", ["1|N"]]],
  "Pa" => [["1", ["1|S", "3|D", "5|H"]], ["4", ["7|K"]]]
}
```

I found the following code with `merge`, and tried to apply it to my issue, but I got an error:

```
a.merge(b) {|key, a_val, b_val| a_val.merge b_val }
# >> NoMethodError: undefined method `merge' for [["1", ["1", "2"]], ["2", ["1"]]]:Array
```

I even got an error with `a + b`:

```
a + b
# >> NoMethodError: undefined method `+' for #<Hash:0x0000060078e460>
```

*<<<< UPDATE >>>>*

Thanks both Cary and tadman. Outside the original question I show the input file I have and the output I´m tryng to obtain. I show in order for you get an idea why
I generated 2 hashes in that way. In the output I create blocks where fathers are unique values of column 1, below children (unique values in column 2 related with col 1).
Column 3 are subchildren that belong to a value in col2 and column 4 are text contents related with col3.

Probably hash "c" is easier to generate from the beginning.

*This is my input file*

```
Main,Stage1,Stage2,Description
Us,1,1,F
Us,1,2,O
Us,2,1,N
Pa,1,1,S
Pa,1,3,D
Pa,1,5,H
Pa,4,7,K
```

*This is the output I almost get.*

```
Main..Stage1..Stage2..Description       
Us      
......1
..............1.......F
..............2.......O
......2 
..............1.......N
Pa
......1
..............1.......S
..............3.......D
..............5.......H
......4
..............7.......K
```

Then I was able to create this code, but like tadman says, I need to reorder the way I get this to make easier the things, since
I use 4 hashes. After I create hash "a" and "b" I was stuck, since I needed a unique hash to iterate and be able to print in the output structure shown above.

*My code before post the question*

```
X = Hash.new{|hsh,key| hsh[key] = [] }
Y = Hash.new{|hsh,key| hsh[key] = [] }
a = Hash.new{|hsh,key| hsh[key] = [] }
b = Hash.new{|hsh,key| hsh[key] = [] }

File.foreach('file.txt').with_index do
    |line, line_num|

    if line_num > 0
        r = line.split(",")

        X[r[0] + "°" + r[1]].push r[2]
        Y[r[0] + "°" + r[1]].push r[3].strip
    end
end

X.each{ |k,v|
    lbs = k.split("°")
    a[lbs[0]].push [ lbs[1], v] #Here I generate hash a
}

Y.each{ |k,v|
    lbs = k.split("°")
    b[lbs[0]].push [ lbs[1], v] #Here I generate hash b
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here is going to require a bit of work to solve because of all the complicated nesting. This would be a lot easier if you did some work to reorder how that data is stored.

Yet you can do this:

```
a={"Us"=>[["1", ["1", "2"]], ["2", ["1"]]], "Pa"=>[["1", ["1", "3", "5"]], ["4", ["7"]]]}
b={"Us"=>[["1", ["F", "O"]], ["2", ["N"]]], "Pa"=>[["1", ["S", "D", "H"]], ["4", ["K"]]]}

c = a.keys.map do |k|
  ah = a[k].to_h
  bh = b[k].to_h

  [
    k,
    ah.keys.map do |ka|
      [
        ka,
        ah[ka].zip(bh[ka]).map do |pair|
          pair.join('|')
        end
      ]
    end
  ]
end.to_h

# => {"Us"=>[["1", ["1|F", "2|O"]], ["2", ["1|N"]]], "Pa"=>[["1", ["1|S", "3|D", "5|H"]], ["4", ["7|K"]]]}
```

The key here is rigorous use of `map` to transform each layer and `zip` to "zipper" two arrays together into pairs that can then be combined with `join` into the desired string target. Cast back to a Hash with `to_h` at the end and you get what you want.

There's an intermediate conversion for each subset to a hash to handle out-of-order situations where one might specify the apparent "keys" in a different sequence.

What you'll want to do is wrap this up in a method with a descriptive name:

```
def hash_compactor(a,b)
  # ... (code) ...
end
```

That'll help keep it modular. Normally I try and create solutions that handle *N* arguments by defining it as:

```
def hash_compactor(*input)
  # ...
end
```

Where `input` is then an array of various sets in the form you've given. The resulting code is surprisingly a lot more complicated.

Note this makes a lot of assumptions about the input being perfectly matched and will explode if that's not the case.

Comment: Thanks so much tadman for take the time to help and explain. I learn from this kind of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you first convert the values of one of the hashes to hashes, as I will explain. Suppose we create a *new `b`*.

```
newbie = b.transform_values(&:to_h)
  #=> {"Us"=>{"1"=>["F", "O"], "2"=>["N"]},
  #    "Pa"=>{"1"=>["S", "D", "H"], "4"=>["K"]}}
```

We can now use `a` and `newbie` to produce the desired return value.

```
a.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),h|
  h[k] = v.map do |first, arr|
    [first, arr.zip(newbie[k][first]).map { |pair| pair.join('|') }]
  end
end
  #=> {"Us"=>[["1", ["1|F", "2|O"]], ["2", ["1|N"]]],
  #    "Pa"=>[["1", ["1|S", "3|D", "5|H"]], ["4", ["7|K"]]]}
```

If `a` can be mutated it's slightly easier.

```
a.each do |k,v|
  v.map! do |first, arr|
    [first, arr.zip(newbie[k][first]).map { |pair| pair.join('|') }]
  end
end
```

The method [Hash#trasform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) made its debut in Ruby v2.4. To support older versions, one compute `newbie` as follows.

```
newbie = b.each_with_object({}) {|(k,v),h| h[k] = v.to_h }
```

Comment: Thanks so much Cary, your solution is shorter and I´ll test both solutions trying to understand better the logic used. Thanks for help and time!

Comment: I show an update in original post the  input and code I used to get hashes a y b for reference.

Answer (score 1):

In this solution we'll keep the original structure.

I've followed your first try but instead of:

```
a.merge(b) {|key, a_val, b_val| a_val.merge b_val }
```

Think about use a new custom merge function like:

```
c = a.merge(b) {|key, a_val, b_val| myMergeArray(a_val, b_val) }
```

Then the new merge function is a simple recursive one:

```
def myMergeArray(a,b,sep = '|')
 c = a
 c.each_with_index { |e, i|
    if c[i].is_a? Array 
        c[i] = myMergeArray(c[i], b[i], sep)
    else
        c[i] = c[i] + sep + b[i] if c[i] != b[i]
    end
        }
 return c
end
```

I've assumed that in case of equal elements, just save one, so e.g. "Y" and "Y" yield just "Y" instead of "Y|Y"

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks L. Jacob for your solution. All 3 solutions worked as I was looking for. For each solution´s logic I´ve learn. Excellent for all contributors!

Comment: You're welcome! glad to know it helps. Guess my solution is simpler but maybe better for you another structure. Cheers!